# How to get all products details on ajax product load page using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser"

Tags: php, parsing, domparser

All

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to getting product details like Title & Price.
This is the code

```
<?php 

// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax');



// Find all SPAN tags that have a class of "myClass"
foreach($html->find('a.title') as $e){  
    echo 'Title: '.$e->outertext . '<br>';
    //$html = file_get_html('http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax/'.$e->outertext);

}

foreach($html->find('span.final-price') as $e)
    echo 'Price:'.$e->outertext . '<br>';


?>
```

Result

```
Title: Micromax X101 (White) 
Title: Micromax X291 (White) 
Title: Micromax X101 (Yellow) 
Title: Micromax X234+ (Wine Red) 
Title: Micromax Ninja 3 A57 (Black) 
Title: Micromax Ninja 4.0 A87 (Black) 
Title: Micromax Bling Q55 (Pearl White) 
Title: Micromax X222 (Cocoa Brown) 
Title: Micromax X263 (Champagne & Coffee) 
Title: Micromax X650 (Silver White) 
Title: Micromax A73 (Black) 
Title: Micromax X1i XTRA (Black) 
Title: Micromax Superfone Lite A75 (Charcoal Black) 
Title: Micromax X271 (Black & Blue) 
Title: Micromax X50 (Black) 
Title: Micromax Q56 (Baby Pink) 
Title: Micromax X104 (Black) 
Title: Micromax Q22 (Black Green) 
Title: Micromax Aisha A52 (Yellow) 
Title: Micromax A78 (Coffee) 
Price:Rs. 999
Price:Rs. 1910
Price:Rs. 999
Price:Rs. 1190
Price:Rs. 4999
Price:Rs. 6049
Price:Rs. 3130
Price:Rs. 2040
Price:Rs. 1735
Price:Rs. 3350
Price:Rs. 6199
Price:Rs. 1525
Price:Rs. 6299
Price:Rs. 1590
Price:Rs. 4850
Price:Rs. 3999
Price:Rs. 1099
Price:Rs. 1880
Price:Rs. 4699
Price:Rs. 6970
```

This works fine, but open this page in your browser http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax. There is ajax product load functionality.

So my script just getting initial loaded products only. I want to get all the products.
You can see "Showing 1-20 of 78". How to get all 78 products details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read their number of products and divide by 20 as 20 are they display and use their AJAX script to get values. This way you can avoid `simple_html_dom` and decode json string:

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax?response-type=json&inf-start=0
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax?response-type=json&inf-start=20
```

and so on.

You just need to check what script it's called during page scroll. In Google Chrome you can use `Developer Tools`, open with <kbd>F12</kbd> and watch for Network section.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. I want to grab data from many e-commerce site. and all are not using ajax load. So is there any of your suggestion on getting ajax load data using DOM parser ? the reason is i do not want to writer each e-commerce site json parser.

Comment: You have to make something different for each website.